# Кодировка при выводе ответа от сервера в текстовое поле

Tags: javascript, ajax, sas

С помощью функции `fetch` (js) получаю ответ от сервера. Ответ приходит в виде простой текстовой строки, в которой в моем случае есть символы кириллицы. При выводе ответа в консоль строка отображается нормально, а вот когда строка появляется в текстовом поле, там стоят знаки вопроса в черных ромбиках.

В заголовке страницы кодировка стоит `utf-8`. Пробовал прописывать `Accept-Language` и `Content-Language` в `headers` внутри `fetch()`, но не помогло.

Пример кода:

```
function SendGet() {
  var url = 'http://..';
  var promise = fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
      //'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU',
      //'Content-Language': 'ru-RU'
    },
    credentials: 'include',
  });
  promise.then(function(data) {
    return data.text();
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    document.getElementById('objDesc').value = response;
  });   
}
```

Мета информация в теге head:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='ru'>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Тег  с функцией SendGet также находится внутри тега head.

Сервер апач (судя по файлу httpd.conf), но я не могу найти .htaccess.

---

Корень веб-сервера.

Ситуация несколько затрудняется тем, что система, с которой я работаю - это не просто один сервис или сайт, а целое веб-приложение с несколькими серверами (сервисами) компании SAS.

Судя по документации корень веб-сервера находится здесь: \SAS\SASConfig\Lev1\Web\WebServer.

Также в документации сказано, что "The server is based on VMware vFabric Web Server". В основе  vFabric Web Server лежит апач.

[image: Корень веб-сервера]

Апач также установлен на машине и находится здесь: \SAS\SASHome\SASWebServer\httpd-2.2.

[image: Корень апача]

---

Подскажите, как можно поправить ситуацию?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61580/discussion-on-question-by-drunken-yeti-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить следующим образом.

Отправка http-заголовков с сервера в данном случае не нужна.

В языке SAS отправка данных с сервера клиенту осуществляется через дата-шаг с директивой _webout:

```
data _null_;
   file _webout;
   put "Пример_данных";
run;
```

Чтобы данные с кириллицей корректно отображались не только в консоли разработчика, но и в соответствующем поле (например, текстовом) дата-шаг должен содержать кодировку:

```
data _null_;
   file _webout encoding='utf-8';
   put "Пример_данных";
run;
```

После этого данные в поле будут отображаться корректно.

Answer (score 0):

> Мета информация в теге head

А должна быть в http-заголовках. Исправь - и всё должно заработать.

Comment: Я не понял а где она должна быть? Как в заголовках? если это инфа страницы, или я что то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_HTTP

Comment: Да я вот и об этом, а если у тебя например простая страница например только с `html` как там нужно задать котировку? скажете пример?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не совсем понял вас (или возможно я не правильно выразился). У меня кодировка прописана вот так:

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='ru'>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>

Comment: @DrunkenYeti, в этом и проблема.

Comment: @Qwertiy так в ссылке, которую вы кинули, сделано так же..Или вы имели ввиду, что кодировку нужно прописать внутри параметра headers функции fetch, т.е. вот так:

headers: {
 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
 'Content-Language': 'ru-RU'
}, 

Но, к сожалению, это тоже не помогло(

Comment: @DrunkenYeti, нужно прописать НЕ мета-теги в разметке, а HTTP-ЗАГОЛОВКИ В ОТВЕТЕ СЕРВЕРА!

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, сделал, получилось вот что. 

Прописал old = stpsrv_header("Content-type", "text/html; encoding=utf-8"); (это функция языка SAS, которая устанавливает заголовки). 

В итоге мне пришло вот так (Response Headers): 
Content-Type:text/html;encoding=utf-8; charset=UTF-8

При этом знаки вопроса, которые были до этого только в самом текстовом поле (в консоли все было ок), появились и в консоли. Если эту функцию из кода убрать, то будет кодировка windows-1251, в консоли все будет нормально, а в поле как были вопросы так и останутся.

Comment: Ну так шли кодировку, соответствующую ответу. Зачем ты ставишь кодировку utf8, если у тебя данные в 1251?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я попробовал поставить windows-1251 (в заголовке от сервера). В итоге в консоли выводит нормально (как если бы функции с заголовками не было вовсе; при этом сейчас к параметру encoding пришлось добавить еще и charset, потому что если в charset принудительно не указать windows-1251, то туда почему-то приходит utf-8), но в текстовом поле все равно остаются вопросы вместо текста...

Comment: @Qwertiy В Response Headers вот так сейчас приходит:
Content-Type:text/html;encoding=windows-1251;charset=windows-1251, но в текстовом поле все равно вопросы...